# Increment the lines if a condition is satisfied till another condition is satisfied

Tags: python-3.x

I am having a dictionary and zip file with below syntax:

```
Dict = {1254: [abcd_qw[5], 56], 4654: [ghfd_yt[7], 42]}
```

File:

```
"pattern 1": Some content... {  // Like wise many other pattern are there. I only want to check the patterns as dict key.
    Some lines...
   "ghdf_yt[7]"=Some content...
   "abcd_qw[5]"=Some content...
 }
"pattern 1254": Some content... {
   Some lines...
   "ghdf_yt[7]"=Some content...
   "abcd_qw[5]"=Some content...
   Other pins contents...
 }
"pattern 4654: Some content... {
   Some lines...
   "ghdf_yt[7]"=Some content...
   "abcd_qw[5]"=Some content...
   Other pin contents...
  }

Similarly there are many lines...
```

I want is to read this file till pattern 1254 is in the line and incremnent the reading only till it finds abcd_qw[5] in the next lines...

Flowchart:

[image: Flow Chart]

I have tried the below code:

```
file = gzip.open(stil_file, 'r')

for line in stil_file.readlines():
    for (key, value) in Details.items():
        string1 = "\"pattern " + str(key) + "\":"
        if string1.encode('utf-8') in line:
            print(line)
            string2 = "\"" + str(value[0]) + "\"="
            if string2.encode('utf-8') in line:
                print(line)
```

The issue I am facing is it is printing the line with pattern 1254 but not the line with abcd_qw[5]. Obviously, it is not able to increment the lines after satisfying the first condition.

Can someone please help me with the code? Also, would appreciate if the code reduces the run-time.

Thanks & Regards,

Parth.

Answer (score 0):

A few things of note:

1. You're looking for both the key and the value on the same line, which cannot happen with the input format you're dealing with. Instead, when you match a key, save its corresponding value into a variable so that you can look for it in the following lines.
2. You can open open the gzip file in text mode to avoid having to encode the string you're searching for.
3. Use regex to more easily search for the pattern that contains a key and to capture the key within.
4. Directly read the corresponding value in the `Details` dict by key instead of inefficiently iterating over it.

Below is an example of what can be done:

```
import re

with gzip.open(stil_file, 'rt') as file:
    for line in file:
        if match := re.search(r'pattern (\d+)'):
            expected = f'"{Details[match.group(1)]}"='
        elif expected not in line:
            continue
        print(line)
```

Comment: The file is also having many other pattern number...I wanted to take the selected number which is present as dictionary key. The above regex will take all the other pattern lines as well... Also, Further I will need to edit the content after = for the value0 line...

Comment: I have edited the text file format to avoid the confusion.

Comment: I have also added the flow-chart. So, it will be clear what I want to do.